# TFS 2010 Team Build Get Sources After Deleting Source Directory on Build Machine

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a TFS Build that runs overnight. The build source can be found on the agent in c:\build\3\poject\build def\Sources.

The \Sources folder was accidentally deleted (guilty). I would have expected TFS to "Get" the latest source prior to the next build. It seems that it doesn't do this - it just complains that it can't find any of the sources to build.

Can anyone please tell me how I force TFS to get the latest sources to the build agents \sources folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a way to cause a full redownload of source from the build definition but I am not seeing an option right now.  You should be able to fix this on the build machine itself.  If you cd into the Source directory and then run tf get /force it should redownload all of the content.  Subsequent builds after this should work.

Comment: Wouldn't the "tf get" only get the code into my workspace? I need to get the code back to the TFS build location. I realise that I could just manually copy the files from my workspace but wanted to check if there was an automatic way of having TFS do this for me

Comment: On the build machine, the build service has its own workspace.  I am asking you to run "tf get /force" in the build service's workspace on the build machine.  It will repopulate the workspace that the build machine builds out of.

Answer (score 2):

Under the Build Definition -> Process what is the Clean Workspace parameter set to?  If it is set to All it should cause the entire source to be downloaded on each build.

[image: Clean Workspace Option]